# Calculate formula in closedxml

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I used a formula in closedxml:

```
var result = worksheet.Cell(3, 8);
result.FormulaA1 = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(G3,OrganizationUnitsById,2,FALSE))," 
                 + "" 
                 + ",VLOOKUP(G3,OrganizationUnitsById,2,FALSE))";
```

When I used this formula before, it worked perfectly. But then I changed something, then this formula didn't calculate automatically. I saved file from an application, this formula works but didn't calculate automatically.

What is wrong?

Comment: I created it in ClosedXML.But calculation didn't happen. When i open excel and i enter this formula again, then it calculation

Comment: How can I do the calculation by another way?

Comment: But ClosedXML has calculation mode property, i used it, it didn't work again

Comment: ClosedXML never calculate the formulas? Before i could do it by ClosedXML. But now doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried with ClosedXML 0.89.0-beta1? It's available on Nuget.

Comment: I'm the ClosedXML maintainer. As @rene said in a comment below, if you can give a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, I can try look into it for you. It might be a ClosedXML bug; it might be a problem with your file.

Answer (score 4):

My experiments have revealed that your formula throws the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in ClosedXML.dll

Here is the testrig:

```
var wb = new ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook();        
var worksheet = wb.AddWorksheet("test");

worksheet.Cell("G3").Value = "fu";

worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = "fu";
worksheet.Cell("B1").Value = "bar";
worksheet.Cell("C1").Value = "baz";
worksheet.Cell("A2").Value = "fu2";
worksheet.Cell("B2").Value = "bar2";
worksheet.Cell("C2").Value = "baz2";

worksheet.Range("A1:C2").AddToNamed("OrganizationUnitsById");

var result = worksheet.Cell(3, 8);
result.FormulaA1 = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(G3,OrganizationUnitsById,2,FALSE)),"
                 + ""
                 + ",VLOOKUP(G3,OrganizationUnitsById,2,FALSE))";
wb.CalculateMode = ClosedXML.Excel.XLCalculateMode.Auto;
Console.WriteLine(result.Value); // throws exception
```

The reason it throws is caused by the use of the `ISNA` function in your formula. It [isn't yet implemented](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/blob/develop/ClosedXML/Excel/CalcEngine/Functions/Information.cs#L89). Removing `ISNA` from your formula resolves the calculation issues but that will lead to different behavior of that formula.

You have to find an alternative for the `ISNA` function. At the date of writing, pick one of these: ISBLANK, ISEVEN, ISLOGICAL, ISNUMBER, ISODD, ISTEXT, N or shape the data in your lookup table so you don't need the check for `ISNA.

As my example is tested with 0.88 you could fetch the beta release ClosedXML 0.89.0-beta1 because `ISNA` is implemented in [PR441](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/pull/441).

Comment: But when i used this formula:  "=VLOOKUP(G3, OrganizationUnitsById, 2, FALSE) .Result is same

Comment: When I open, it will work the first row in a table, then if I want to enter the second or third.. rows in a table, calculation will not work. It is problem. Can you understand me?

Comment: No, I don't. it would really help if you create an [MCVE] in your question, similar to what I did that, and reproduces your problem. Your current question is answered.

Comment: I write this formula in ClosedXML, and I want to create a template in my application.When I save the template and open excel, this formula works first row in the table. But when I go to the second row and selected any value, the calculation doesn't work. I must select the formula again and click enter button, then calculation works again. But i dont want to click enter, I want when i create this formula and save template, works all rows in the table

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/9BwDB  look at this picture.Maybe you can understand

Comment: No, I still don't understand and your problem now seems to be different from the initial question you asked. I don't feel much to spend my time on hunting down bugs in code I don't see, nor do I fancy debugging from screenshots. Either ask a new question with a proper [MCVE] or let me know why my current answer doesn't work for you, given the question you asked initially.

Comment: `NA()` and other functions from the `Information` category were implemented in https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/pull/441

Comment: @FrancoisBotha thanks, I picked stable 0.88 and verified in the master branch in the implementation was there.

Comment: @rene PR 441 hasn't been merged yet. Whatever you saw in the `master` branch will soon be updated.